# Is there a more efficient way to display the sum of two arrays using For Loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want the end result to display "276 + 351 = 627". Is there a more efficient way to do so while using for loops?
This is a practice question I found online, so the stuff after the 2 arrays is what I've come up with.

```
let arr_1 = [3, 5, 22, 5,  7,  2,  45, 75, 89, 21, 2];
let arr_2 = [9, 2, 42, 55, 71, 22, 4,  5,  90, 25, 26];

let sum1 = 0;
let sum2 = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr_1.length; i++) {
    sum1 += arr_1[i];
}
for (let j = 0; j < arr_2.length; j++) {
    sum2 += arr_2[j];
}

let total = sum1 + sum2;

console.log(`${sum1} + ${sum2} = ${total}`);
```

Comment: To answer your question, there is no way to do it more efficiently. Using an array method like `reduce` might look tidier but it won't be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function allows you to write it in a very short manner:

```js
const arr_1 = [3, 5, 22, 5,  7,  2,  45, 75, 89, 21, 2],
      arr_2 = [9, 2, 42, 55, 71, 22, 4,  5,  90, 25, 26],
      add   = arr => arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + n),
      sum1  = add(arr_1),
      sum2  = add(arr_2),
      total = sum1 + sum2;

console.log(`${sum1} + ${sum2} = ${total}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

There many way to loop through a array if you read the MDN Docs [Link Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).
One of the way is **reduce()** which work with almost all browsers but i would prefer to use **forEach()** as it is one of oldest proto on arrays.. and here is how it is done

```
let arr_1 = [3, 5, 22, 5, 7, 2, 45, 75, 89, 21, 2];
let arr_2 = [9, 2, 42, 55, 71, 22, 4, 5, 90, 25, 26];

let sum1 = 0
let sum2 = 0
let total = 0

arr_1.forEach((el) => {
  sum1 += el
});
arr_2.forEach((el) => {
  sum2 += el
});
total = sum1 + sum2

console.log(`${sum1} + ${sum2} = ${total}`);
```

JSFiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/v79Lx35q/)

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const
  doSum = arr => arr.reduce((a,c)=>a+c,0)  // let zero value, if arr is empty
, arr_1 = [ 3, 5, 22, 5,  7,  2,  45, 75, 89, 21, 2 ]
, arr_2 = [ 9, 2, 42, 55, 71, 22, 4,  5,  90, 25, 26 ] 
, sum1  = doSum(arr_1) 
, sum2  = doSum(arr_2)
, total = sum1 + sum2
;
console.log(`${sum1} + ${sum2} = ${total}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both `arr_1` and `arr_2` have the same length, you only need one loop. This is as efficient (as in speed/performance) as you'll get:

```js
let sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0,
    arr_1 = [3, 5, 22, 5,  7,  2,  45, 75, 89, 21, 2],
    arr_2 = [9, 2, 42, 55, 71, 22, 4,  5,  90, 25, 26];

for (let i = 0; i < arr_1.length; i++) {
    sum1 += arr_1[i], sum2 += arr_2[i];
}

let total = sum1 + sum2;

console.log(`${sum1} + ${sum2} = ${total}`);
```

Plain `for` loops are typically faster than more high level looping functions, so you already have the best performing loop possible.

You could also use this for arrays of different lengths by looping the larger one, still only doing one `for` loop:

```js
let sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0,
    arr_1 = [3, 5, 22, 5,  7,  2,  45, 75, 89, 21, 2, 6, 40, 4],
    arr_2 = [9, 2, 42, 55, 71, 22, 4,  5,  90, 25, 26];

for (let i = 0; i < arr_1.length; i++) {
    sum1 += arr_1[i], sum2 += arr_2[i] || 0;
}

let total = sum1 + sum2;

console.log(`${sum1} + ${sum2} = ${total}`);
```

When `arr_2` runs out, it will start outputting `undefined`. The `arr_2[i] || 0` expression will use the secondary value in that case.

An alternative would be to check if the offset exists:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < arr_1.length; i++) {
    sum1 += arr_1[i];
    if(arr_2[i]) sum2 += arr_2[i];
}
```